# How to add dropdown select box in JSF with from the backingbean? (dynamic form creation)

Tags: forms, jsf, select, javabeans

I want to dynamically create a form with my bean. I am using JSF 2.0

```
How do I include a select box?
```

I add a text-field like follow:

My JSF page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{formBacking.beanAction}"/>
</f:metadata>
...
<h:panelGroup binding="#{formBacking.panelGroup}"/>
```

In my backing bean:

```
private HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup;

public void beanAction() {
        panelGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        panelGroup.setLayout("block");
        panelGroup.setStyleClass("grid-form");

        HtmlPanelGroup line1 = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        HtmlPanelGroup line2 = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        HtmlPanelGroup line3 = new HtmlPanelGroup();

        //line1
        HtmlOutputText text1 = new HtmlOutputText();
        text1.setValue("Line 1 - HtmlOutputText");
        line1.getChildren().add(text1);

        //line2
        HtmlOutputLabel label2 = new HtmlOutputLabel();
        label2.setValue("Line 2 - HtmlOutputLabel");
        line2.getChildren().add(label2);

        //line3
        //HOW TO ADD A DROP DOWN SELECT BOX?
}
```